# Why is `.htaccess` causing internal redirections overflow under these RewriteRules?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am making an API in which I had those `.htaccess` rules to make "friendly URLs", so I can make Endpoints that doesn't depend on the presence of a file that matches the URI:

```
Options -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L,NC,QSA]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L,NC,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

The intent of the first rule is: *"if requested filename (in the URL) is not an existing file or directory, then redirect to `index.php`"*. It works very well for that matter.

The intent for the second rule is: *"if requested filename is an existing directory, then redirect to `index.php`"*. It also works like a charm.

**The problem is** that now, I need to fit in a Frontend developed with React.js by another developer, so I need to apply some exceptions to those rules. I tried the following changes to the second `.htaccess` rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/directory_a.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/directory_a/directory_b.*
RewriteRule . /index.php [L,NC,QSA
```

...which intent is like: *"if requested filename is an existing directory, and requested URI doesn't start with `/directory_a` neither with `/directory_a/directory_b`, then and only then redirect to `index.php`"*. The rule works, but it isn't enough, because it still redirects existing files within those directories. So, in order to fix that, I tried the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/directory_a.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/directory_a/directory_b.*
RewriteRule . /index.php [L,NC,QSA
```

...almost the same than the previous modification, but asking for existing files as well. Here, I guess the conditions would work (expressed as pseudo-code) like this (but I'm not sure about it at all), prioritizing `OR` over `AND`:

```
IF ( is_existing_file OR is_existing_directory )
AND NOT uri.startswith( '/directory_a' )
AND NOT uri.startswith( '/directory_a/directory_b' )
```

...anyway, this is not working: it makes the `Apache` server to crash with an `HTTP 500` (Internal Server Error) that throws the following error in `error_log`:

> AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

...I wonder why this happens at all, and if is it possible to achive what I am trying to achieve here via `.htaccess`...

**My API is deployed in `DocumentRoot`, as well as it's `index.php` and `.htaccess` file.**

Comment: well, `/index.php` fits your pseudocode criteria, therefore you get the loop?

Comment: @DusanBajic so, that implies the redirection to `/index.php` also loops back to the same condition over and over?? Oops... If that's so, perhaps excluding `/index.php` would fix the problem. I'll give it a try...

Comment: The real question seems to be "why (without that last `-f` line) are existing files within those 2 folders being redirected"

Comment: (I don’t really get why you started by checking `!-d` and `-d` separately, only to then redirect to the same place in both instances anyway.)

Comment: @04FS it is because, by default, I want to redirect any non-existing file and directory to `index.php`. And I want to do the same with existing files and directories only if they are not within the `/directory_a` and `/directory_a/directory_b/`... that is why.

Comment: Just asking, because you said you had these rules _before_ already …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that excluding `index.php` in the conditions, solves the problem. Thanks, @DusanBajic :-)

```
Options -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L,NC,QSA]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/directory_a.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/directory_a/directory_b.*
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L,NC,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: If you have `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/directory_a.*` condition then you don't really need redundant condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/directory_a/directory_b.*`

Comment: You are right. Technically, the first `RewriteCond`'s regular expression would match `/directory_a/directory_b` as well...

Answer (score 1):

You may use these rules:

```
Options -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # ignore rules below this for URIs starting with /directory_a/
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+directory_a[/?\s]
    RewriteRule . - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Note that we are using `THE_REQUEST` here, which doesn't change after executing rewrite rules. `REQUEST_URI` on the other hand gets updated after executing rewrite rules

Comment: It looks like an interesting approach... now I wonder if it is better than my self-answer for some reason...

Comment: Thank you @anubhava sir for sharing nice solution, you are CHAMP of htaccess. Would like to request you if you could guide me how I could learn it too? And most important how will I verify or run my solution before posting on SO, will be grateful sir if you could guide me on same.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: Just install a readily available LAMP stack on Windows or install Apache+PHP using `home brew` on Mac. https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/ is a good place to start learning .htaccess and then of course we have tons of SO answers